# H2 and IMG in an A tag - highlight both on hover

Tags: html, css

I'd like to ask if it's possible to apply hover on both the IMG and the H2 tags inside the A tag?

E.g.:

```
<a href="/something">
    <img src="/img/something.png" onmouseover="this.src = '/img/something-alt.png';" onmouseout="this.src = '/img/something.png';">
    <h2 class="margin-top">Something</h2>
</a>
```

So the H2 tag is set to the A:HOVER color, and the image is switched to the alternative.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, but part of SO is that you try to solve it yourself. Show your working, show what part you got stuck on. It's not a do-work-for-me service.

Comment: Ehh, it's not like someone is asking for an algorithm without even thinking, if I don't know the name of the technique I can't really search for it and CSS cannot be solved by pure logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put both the normal and alternate images into separate img tags.

```
<a href="/something" class="big-link">
    <img src="/img/something.png" class="image-main">
    <img src="/img/something-alt.png" class="image-alt">
    <h2 class="margin-top">Something</h2>
</a>
```

Then the CSS would be:

```
.big-link .image-alt{
    display:none;
}
.big-link:hover .image-alt{
    display:inline;
}
.big-link:hover .image-main{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think that was I've been looking for. I'll try it right away, and accept your answer when the timer allows. Thanks again! (EDIT: works :))